# Doing something only when the draft option is on?

Tags: conditionals, document-classes, draft

I would like to do some stuff that is only enabled when the `draft` option is given in `\documentclass[draft]{article}`.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `draft` option sets `\overfullrule` to 5pt; so you can say

```
\makeatletter
\def\ifdraft{\ifdim\overfullrule>\z@
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi}
\makeatother
```

and say

```
\ifdraft{do this, we are in draft mode}{do that, we aren't in draft mode}
```

Note that `\ifdraft` is not a real conditional, so perhaps it should be named `\@ifdraft` but this would force you to use it in definitions between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

Of course, you shouldn't be setting `\overfullrule` yourself.

Answer (score 57):

There is also the [`ifdraft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ifdraft) package that does what you want.

It defines `\ifdraft{Do in draft}{Do in final}` and some others

Comment: That works really well. I am surprised to see it even works with environments.