# Add when the file was compiled to the draft document.

Tags: include, draft

I would like to have on my draft-documents on the bottom something like `compiled ch2.tex on July 21, 2011 at 18:46`. My document has multiple files which I include by using `\input`.

I have the following preamble (I only kept the relevant part):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, leqno, draft]{scrbook} %draft
\usepackage{scrtime}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{fancyref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{calc}
\fancyheadoffset[LE,RO]{\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage} 
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhead{} % get rid of headers
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{10pt} % and the line
}
\lfoot{\scriptsize{\texttt{compiled \currfilename \ on \today \ at \thistime}}}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}

\author{Jonas Teuwen}
\title{}

\begin{document}

\input{ch1.tex}
\input{ch2.tex}

\end{document}
```

The line that gives problems is the following:

```
\lfoot{\scriptsize{\texttt{compiled \currfilename \ on \today \ at \thistime}}}
```

It does work, it gives me the correct result, however, at the last page of `ch1.tex` at the bottom LaTeX already prints the line for `ch2.tex`. What is wrong?

Another small question: How do I automatically disable this part if the document is set as `[final]` instead of `[draft]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to flush the last page of the chapter with `\clearpage` (or `\newpage`), otherwise LaTeX will already have opened file `ch2.tex` and `\currfilename` then holds that name.

Chapter should be included using `\include` which adds `\clearpage` automatically, not using `\input`. (You can also then use e.g. `\includeonly{ch1}` to only compile chapter 1.)

You can use the `ifdraft` package to only add this line only in draft mode:

```
\ifdraft{%
\lfoot{\scriptsize{\texttt{compiled \currfilename \ on \today \ at \thistime}}}%
}{}
```

(See also [Doing something only when the draft option is on?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21234/doing-something-only-when-the-draft-option-is-on/21238#21238))

Note that with the `filemod` package you can also add the file modification date.

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I wanted.