# obtain a pdf free of figures and table

Tags: floats, compiling

Is there a way to obtain a pdf file without figures and tables, while maintaining the figure numbers in the body text.

Thank you very much

Comment: For the `graphicx`-package the option `draft` exists, which replaces all images included with it with placeholders.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21234/doing-something-only-when-the-draft-option-is-on .

Comment: Thank you for your response.  But I would like to obtain only the text, without placeholder

Comment: The answer in my link tells you how to achieve that.

Comment: Did you look at [endfloat](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/endfloat?lang=en)?  You could just remove the final pages from the resulting PDF...

Comment: Excuse me, I don't find a response fot that in this link, whan you use the draft option the figures are replaced by white box

Comment: You could use the `\ifdraft` from that link and wrap it around all your tables and figures. This way you accomplish the stuff you want.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try that. But I hope that there is an easy manner. I have just a article to check. But imagine the case of a thesis or a book ; you would like to obtain a free version, what will be the solution !!

Answer (score 2):

You might use the following utilizing the `ifdraft` package:

```
\documentclass[draft]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{ifdraft}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\tabledraft}[2]{%
    \ifdraft{\refstepcounter{table}\label{#1}}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\figuredraft}[2]{%
    \ifdraft{\refstepcounter{figure}\label{#1}}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}
\figuredraft{fig:ex-a}{
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Example image a}\label{fig:ex-a}
    \end{figure}
}
\tabledraft{tab:ex}{
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{A neat table}\label{tab:ex}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            \hline
            neat&table\\
            being&neat\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
}

Some random text.


Figure \ref{fig:ex-a} is nice but table \ref{tab:ex} is even nicer.

\end{document}
```

With `draft`-option resulting in:

[image: results with draft]

And without it resulting in:

[image: results without draft]

Answer (score 2):

This solution (using Skillmon's MWE) makes the figure or table invisible, although it actually goes through all the steps of drawing it.

```
\documentclass[draft]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{ifdraft}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\ifdraft{\RenewEnviron{figure}[1][tbp]%
 {\hrule height0pt \rlap{\hspace{\paperwidth}\smash{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
  \def\@captype{figure}\BODY\end{minipage}}}\ignorespaces}}

\ifdraft{\RenewEnviron{table}[1][tbp]%
 {\hrule height0pt \rlap{\hspace{\paperwidth}\smash{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
  \def\@captype{table}\BODY\end{minipage}}}\ignorespaces}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Before text

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Example image a}\label{fig:ex-a}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{A neat table}\label{tab:ex}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            \hline
            neat&table\\
            being&neat\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

After text.

Figure \ref{fig:ex-a} is nice but table \ref{tab:ex} is even nicer.

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: I'm not sure whether I like your solution or not. While it is great, because it doesn't need any restructuring of the code, it is bad because it might add extra vspace because the not shown figures still result in new paragraphs. (is it possible to give half of an upvote?)

Comment: i make a few tweaks,  I had noticed previously the \hrule\null takes up less room the \null by itself.

Comment: Well done. Now the only thing that might be bothering (but being a case which shouldn't ever happen anyway), is that it starts a new paragraph even if there is now space between the environments and the text. Really a nice solution.