# doing something only when document option "final" is declared

Tags: conditionals, document-classes

Similar to [Doing something only when the draft option is on?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21234/doing-something-only-when-the-draft-option-is-on) I wonder whether I can typeset a code only if the `final` option is declared within the `documentclass` line.

```
 \documentclass[final]{article}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Does it solve your problem? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1492

Comment: Thanks @antshar, interesting to read, but, if my skim is correct the suggested solutions there for not point me to how to query for the final option within the document.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the necessity of `\makeatletter`, but the document class option list is an "internal" command.

```
\documentclass[final]{article}

\makeatletter \usepackage[\@classoptionslist]{optional}

\begin{document}

test \opt{final}{FFF}\opt{draft}{DDD}\opt{x}{XXX}.

\end{document}
```

You can, of course, specify specific options to the optional package with

```
\makeatletter \usepackage[x, \@classoptionslist]{optional}
```